# LAST_INSERT_ID(); returns nothing after Insert query

Tags: java, mysql

I'm using multiple queries in one statement in order to register a transaction in a database. The following is the statement being executed to the database:

```
INSERT INTO xfunstock_transactions (uuid, type, date, symbol, quantity, single_price) VALUES (?, 'purchase', ?, ?, ?, ?); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

But when executing that I get this following statement, when it should return the latest ID generated with INSERT INTO.

```
Statement.executeQuery() cannot issue statements that do not produce result sets.
```

The code for executing this statement is as following (using the same connection):

```
public void processTransaction(Transaction transaction) {
        try (Connection connection = pool.getConnection();
             PreparedStatement statement = buildActionStatement(connection, transaction);
             ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery()) {
            if (resultSet.next()) {
                transaction.setId(resultSet.getInt("id"));
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

private PreparedStatement buildActionStatement(Connection connection, Transaction transaction)
            throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(getActionQuery(transaction));
        statement.setString(1, transaction.getUuid().toString());
        statement.setTimestamp(2, Timestamp.from(transaction.getDate()));
        statement.setString(3, transaction.getSymbol().toUpperCase());
        statement.setInt(4, transaction.getQuantity());
        statement.setString(5, transaction.getSinglePrice().toPlainString());
        if (transaction.getEarnings() != null) {
            statement.setString(6, transaction.getEarnings().toPlainString());
        }

        return statement;
    }
```

I'm using the HikariCP library, and have tried setting "allowMultiQueries" to true, but it still doesn't work as intended.

Comment: You have a combination of pure SQL (`SELECT`) and DM (`INSERT`)L.  If you want to run them as a single operation you will need to define a stored procedure and call it accordingly.

Comment: *Statement.executeQuery() cannot issue statements that do not produce result sets.* - this means that executeQuery() cannot be used for INSERT.

Comment: @Akina - You're right. My bad. I just needed somehow to distinguish between `executeQuery` and `executeUpdate`` in JDBC)